# Django request GET QuerySet parsing

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I recieve this as GET data:

```
<QueryDict: {u'modal[name]': [u'Storm Security'], u'modal[slug]': [u'storm-security']}>
```

I need to parse that, into this:

```
{'name': 'Storm Security', 'slug': 'storm-security'}
// or
{'modal': {'name': 'Storm Security', 'slug': 'storm-security'}}
```

Is there a pythonist way to do so without Regex or splitting keys?

The creepy part is that those keys are formed by stringified `"modal[indexes]"`

Comment: Why do you have the key as `modal[name]` ? Just send it as `'name': ['Storm Security']` You can do `request.GET.getlist('modal[name]')` and extract the values the way you want. or just `request.GET.copy()`

Comment: I think the problem is why you have the dict with such weird key name. There are two direction you can work on: 1. check the function which send this request (javascript maybe?) and see if you send the data properly; second, as Karthikr suggest, use getlist in Django, or you can try json.loads(request.GET.get('modal[name]')).

Comment: a one liner but involves a little stripping: `{str(k.strip('[modal]')):str(v[0]) for k, v in d.items()}` --- > `{'name': 'Storm Security', 'slug': 'storm-security'}`

Comment: @HerrActress stripping is not a good idea, see what happens if the key is `modal[mouse]`, for example.

Comment: @JerryMeng You're right, my javascript send a request with data containing a JSON, but before sending, I insert that data inside another JSON, like `data: {"modal": JSON}`, just to keep a pattern purpose in the project. In this way I know all GET requests which is inside `modal` comes from a modalBox request.

Comment: @alecxe - I knew i was missing something, that's why I did not post it as an answer

Comment: I don't know whether you like it or not, but can you try to change     data: {"modal": JSON} to data: JSON.stringify({"modal":JSON}). And in the view, try to loads it as a json? I mean the point is that when sending nested json via ajax, its key names got messed up. I remember I deal it as the way, above. May need more debug work, though.

Comment: @JerryMeng I actually tried that as: JSON.strigify('{"modal":'+ myJson +'}'), didn't work and I left as before... Thanks for the tip

Comment: well, sorry for it doesn't work. It is hard for giving more tips since there is no actually code I can work on. However, general idea for this kind of problem, sending nested structure data (json in json, list in json, json in list) always cause issues when try to parse them in view. What JSON.strigify does is to make the data to pure string which give you a chance to do something like json.loads to convert it back to json. It may not work exactly this way in your case, but I believe it is the way you should think about. Best wish, dude.

Comment: Yeah @JerryMeng, i had to give up sending `data: {"modal":myJson}`, i'm sending it as `data:myJson`, it's pretty easier to work at the backend, unfortunately lost in project stardatization... Thank you, man. :)